# Tiny space only on mobile versus desktop (stacking divs with pos absolute / css)

Tags: html, css, forms

My goal was to stack two forms over each other so the outside borders aligned perfectly. I got it to work and look exactly how I want it to on the desktop site but viewing it on my mobile phone I noticed the "red box" isn't exactly on top of the other one and is slightly higher. (Like no more than 1 or 2px)

If I lower the red box to make it look right on the mobile version than the desktop version gets screwed up.

I've eliminated all margins, and tested various positioning "absolute" in and out of div's to try and eliminate this weird extra space but I still can't figure out what's causing the discrepancy in the mobile version versus the desktop version.

CSS (Included animated transitions) - if you need me to edit the code some more just let me know (sorry I'm still fairly new here)

```css
.wrappercirclenamesearchcats {
  top: 10%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
 }
 .circlelogo1 {
  position: relative;
  background: #007580;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  /* Child elements with absolute positioning will be positioned relative to this div */
 }
 .circlelogo2 {
  position: absolute;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 32px;
  width: 32px;
  /* Put top edge and left edge in the center */
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -16px 0 0 -16px;
  /* Offset the position correctly with minus half of the width and minus half of the height */
 }
 .name {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 45px;
  font-weight: 300;
  top: 25px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  color: #007580;
 }
 .searchcontainer {
  position: relative;
  height: 36px;
  top: 45px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 400px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
 }
 input[type=text] {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  padding: 8px 40px;
  /* 1st size of box 2nd moves words right */
  background-image: url('https://image.ibb.co/j9esac/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 7px;
  /* 1st moves right 2nd moves down */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  font-size: 17px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
 }
 .categories {
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: 300;
  word-spacing: 26px;
  top: 66.5px;
  @include fluid-type(font-size, 413px, 1200px, 14px, 16px);
 }
 .categories a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
 }
 @media screen and (max-width: 413px) {
  .categories {
   font-size: 14px;
  }
 }
 @media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  .categories {
   font-size: 16px;
  }
 }
 .formcontainer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
 }
 input[type=unams] {
  width: 70%;
  padding: 12px 50px;
  margin: 22px 0 0 0;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  background-image: url('https://image.ibb.co/fZHHnc/signin.png');
  background-position: 10px 8px;
  /* 1st controls move right 2nd move down */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 25px;
  /* username icon size */
  box-sizing: border-box;
 }
 input[type=password] {
  width: 70%;
  padding: 12px 50px;
  /* first is how big you want the input box 2nd is positioning of word password */
  margin: 22px 0 15px 0;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  background-image: url('https://image.ibb.co/jC7gfx/lock.png');
  background-position: 10px 8px;
  /* 1st controls move right 2nd move down */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 25px;
  /* lock icon size */
  box-sizing: border-box;
 }
 .loginbutton {
  background-color: #007580;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  width: 30%;
  font-size: 17px;
  height: 38px;
  margin: 0 auto;
 }
```

```html
      <div class="wrappercirclenamesearchcats">
  <a href="index2.html">
         <div class="circlelogo1">
     <div class="circlelogo2">
          </div>
   </div></a>
   <div class="name">Dollar Resources
   </div>
    <div class="searchcontainer">
          <form>
      <input name="search" type="text">
    </form>
        <div class="formcontainer animated slideInRight">
         <form>
        <input type="unams" class="usr" placeholder="Username" name="uname" 
         required>
       <br>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="psw" required>
       <br>
      <button class="loginbutton" type="submit">Log In</button>
      </form>
      </div>     
  </div>
  <div class="categories">
          <a href="#"><b>Categories</b></a> <a href="#home">Newest</a> <a 
      href="#about">Popular</a> <a href="#about">Music</a> <a 
      href="#about">Youth</a>
  </div>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most absolute solution to this problem would be the use of media queries. Check here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Media queries will help you design and tailor your website to work on all sizes you specify.

If media queries don't work for you, then another method would be making your bottom form's position relative, adding "overflow-x: hidden;" to your body and animating the margin-left/left of the form. With the position set to relative, rather than fixed or absolute,, it should always remain under the first form (it shouldn't overlay on top of other elements because the position will take into account all the elements surrounding it).

Comment: A media query shouldn't be needed if I'm keeping everything the same. What is causing the difference in the form positions? I also don't want the red box form underneath the grey one. I want the form directly on top where it looks blended. The reason for this is because I will make the grey box form exit left with a css animation leaving only the second red form in its place.

Comment: you may need media queries to fit all screen sizes. If you want to keep mobile based layout, there's different resolutions too, so media queries can get rid on it, if you don't use it it will be overflowing or moved to a non desired place due to absolute positioning. 
Use responsive measurements to reach this job with absolute position and it will be all ok.

Comment: Thanks guys, I guess I will go ahead and use some MQ's. I just didn't want to because I thought it could be solved with some CSS coding/editing/adding. I still think that this could be fixed without a media query but I'm not going to waste any more time

Comment: yup, media queries are CSS coding, i recommend you to see the example i've just posted, it may lets you work with your code, simply changing the measures.

Answer (score 1):

you can use media queries, but i don't recommend you to use absolute positioning due to responsiveness, unless you use responsive measurements  (vh, vw, vmin, vmax, em, rem). i would recommend you to use wherever but em and rem, because are font-size based, and vh vw, vmin vmax are related to viewport.

it's not a quick job to set the media queries or the alignment with this measurements so i'll let you the doc to you can do it properly.

Address to w3c:

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp

Media queries link that @braijon-g posted already:

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

if you don't want to use any of these options listed before, you can use javascript or jQuery to reach this job, using (example with jQuery):

```
function windowSize(){
//get the height of the window
    var height = $(window).height();
//get the width of the window
    var width = $(window).width();
   /* Some calculations to set the items on desired % of the screen, for example: */
   //in this case i want this item to have the full screen less 100px of margin
   desiredWidth = width - 100;
   //adding this calculation to the desired item:
   $('.desiredItem').css('width', desiredWidth);
}
//this will call and apply the windowSize function to move elements or whatever
$(document).ready(function(){
    windowSize();
});
//if you resize the window, it will call the windowSize function again to recalc the position dynamically
$(window).resize(function{
    windowSize();
});
```

Anyway i would recommend you to run over CSS to reach this, is faster, lighter and more recommendable.

```css
div.e{
position: absolute;
top: 5vh;
left: 25vmin;
}
h1.a{
position: absolute;
left: 20vmin;
}
p.m{
 position: absolute;
 top: 35vh;
 left: 30vmax;
}

p.l, p.e{
 position: absolute;
 min-width: 50vmax;
 top: 25vmin;
 left: 30vmax;
}
p.e{
  top: 20vmin;
}
```

```html
<div class="e">
  <div class="x">
    <h1 class="a"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet </h1>
    <p class="m"> text text text text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="p">
    <p class="l"> text2 text2 text2 text2 </p>
    <p class="e"> text3 text3 text3 </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Example using absolute position with responsive measurements.

It's only to show you how different responsive measurements can work.

If you open it at full screen it will fit different than in the little screen, this is due to the use of different type of measurements.
You can use vh and vw for being more exact, or use vmin and vmax, but not blend it on a real project because the difference on their calcs.